# What is wrong with my question on arXiv?

Tags: discussion

I am unable to understand the comments and the down-votes on [this question of mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11470/5851).
[The question is deleted now, original text reproduced below]

> I realize we do not have a definitive answer/guideline on the purpose of pre-print archives. I guess it will be useful for our users who are new to academia.
>   I would like to see details in terms of:
>   What is the purpose of archives for electronic pre-prints of scientific papers, such arXiv, vixra, SSRN etc.?
>   Why are they needed when conferences/journals already exist to publish papers?
>   Can a published work (i.e., post-print) also go to arXiv?
>   Will my paper accepted by arXiv count as a 'publication' for me?

Is it such a bad idea, say, if we make it a community wiki with one pre-print/e-print service per answer? This is one way of improving it which strikes me. Can others point out the flaws and give inputs on improvement?

Comment: Why the downvote? I think it is great that users want to improve their questions.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub You're right, it's good that users want to improve their questions. I was down-voting for the suggestion to make it a community-wiki.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset fair enough. I just wanted to make sure pnp didn't think we were out to get him/her.

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT:** Since the original question has been deleted, the quoted text in my answer refers to the original question.

> I realize we do not have a definitive answer/guideline on the purpose of pre-print archives. I guess it will be useful for our users who are new to academia.

Ac.SE is a Q&A site, and does not aim at being a "guideline on the purpose" of anything, even if it's related to academia. You might want to look at Wikipedia for that.

Your question is vague, and talk about different, unrelated aspects.

> What is the purpose of archives for electronic pre-prints of scientific papers, such arXiv, vixra, SSRN etc.?

You can find this information on the related sites: http://arxiv.org/help/general

> Why are they needed when conferences/journals already exist to publish papers?

This sounds more like a discussion rather than an actual question. If you don't need it, then why do you care? If you need them, then you probably don't need to ask.

> Can a published work (i.e., post-print) also go to arXiv?

[Does publishing a paper on arXiv prevent me from submitting it to a non-open access journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7/does-publishing-a-paper-on-arxiv-prevent-me-from-submitting-it-to-a-non-open-acc)

> Will my paper accepted by arXiv count as a 'publication' for me?

[Can something published on arXiv or optimization-online.org be mentioned in my CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/can-something-published-on-arxiv-or-optimization-online-org-be-mentioned-in-my-c)

I down-voted this question because you don't make the effort to come up with a clear and concise question you're facing. I didn't want to cast a vote to close it as unclear/non constructive, in order not to abuse mod privileges. Ac.SE is **not** a forum or a discussion board.

Answer (score 6):

> It such a bad idea, say, if we make it a community wiki with one
>   pre-print/e-print service per answer?

Yes, it is a bad idea. I think the [SO blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) on the subject sums it up nicely:

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve
>   this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?”

Changing the question to community wiki does not improve it. As for how to improve it, the "question" had 4 bullet point questions. Each one of those seems to me to be independent of the others so that the question could be broken into 4 more manageable chunks. In breaking it up, I think you would then see the discussion oriented nature of some of the parts and the duplication of other parts.